# How to add toAlternatingCase custom method to String class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a *custom method* to the **String** class in JavaScript called **toAlternatingCase**, it will turn lowercase characters into uppercase and vice versa in the string that is called on, I'm trying to make it like the built-in **toUpperCase/toLowerCase** methods which don't take any arguments.
this is a kata(challenge) on [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56efc695740d30f963000557/train/javascript).

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: I like this method-idea.  You might also consider...passing-in an optional-argument that allows people to request CAMEL or other casing-styles (you would have to rename the function though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by utilizing the **prototype** method to extend the String class. This probably isn't the most efficient way of doing this, but it can be achieved with something like this:

```js
String.prototype.toAlternatingCase = function() {
  var ns = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) ns += (this.slice(i, i+1) == this.slice(i, i+1).toUpperCase()) ? this.slice(i, i+1).toLowerCase() : this.slice(i, i+1).toUpperCase();
  return ns;
}

"String.prototype.toAlternatingCase".toAlternatingCase();
// Should return 'sTRING.PROTOTYPE.TOaLTERNATINGcASE'
```

This just loops through the string and reverses the case of each character, then returns that new result (without modifying the original string).

Comment: your answer gave me food for thought, I think using this method chain  `split('').map().join('')` would be a more elegant way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.toAlternatingCase = function () {
  return this.split("").map(l => l === l.toUpperCase() ? l.toLowerCase() : l.toUpperCase()).join("");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.